# Adding allowedOrigins causes cors error in sameDomain How to fix?

Tags: spring-boot, cors

```
@Configuration
class WebMvcConfig(
    private val authInterceptor: AuthInterceptor,
    private val permissionInterceptor: PermissionInterceptor,
    private val requestUserResolver: RequestUserResolver,
) : WebMvcConfigurer {
    override fun addInterceptors(registry: InterceptorRegistry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(authInterceptor)
            .addPathPatterns("/api/**", "/**") // PtApi 요청만 인증 적용

        registry.addInterceptor(permissionInterceptor)
            .addPathPatterns("/**")
    }

    override fun addArgumentResolvers(resolvers: MutableList<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver>) {
        resolvers.add(requestUserResolver)
    }

    override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
            .allowedOrigins("https://web.B.domain.kr")
            .allowCredentials(true)
    }

    // override fun addFormatters(registry: FormatterRegistry) {
    //     registry.addConverterFactory(StringEnumConverterFactory())
    // }
}
```

The current Spring Boot domain is https://A.domain.kr, access the page like this: https://A.domain.kr/post/1

The problem is https://A.domain.kr/api/v1/saveData
There is an ajax logic with the same domain in the internal logic, but a 403 error occurs,

Any other ajax where path doesn't contain ' api/v1 ' works fine

The suspicious part is the same as the code in the cors part above.
But I don't know why, I wonder if there are other reasons

SameDomain, why is the error occurring?
I don't know why I need to add https://A.domain.kr to cors for it to work normally